# How to prevent adding item to ArrayList (Android)

Tags: java, android, arraylist

so i have a button that when i click on, it add a new object to my ArrayList.

```
private List<Object> addObject = new ArrayList<>();
```

when i click, it does this

```
Object object = new object;
object.setTitle("stuff");
object.isLast = false;
addObject.add(object);
```

This works as it should and then my ArrayList and attached to the adapter...Yada yada yada

At some point in my code, object is going to be true. How i prevent adding to the ArrayList since its the last one.

i tried running a loop

```
for (int i = 1; i < addObject.size(); i++ {
    Object newboject = addObject.get(i);

       if(newobject.getIsLast)){

       //Then i kinda need to stop adding to the list on further clicks. 
       }
}
```

I think the problem may be with how my code is structed, any assistance is appreciated...

Comment: set a flag variable and check this variable before adding? Also i highly recommend to not name your class `Object`.

Comment: yeah, its just for examples sake.. thats y i used object... but can u walk me through setting the flags? @KevinEsche

Comment: You are adding an `object` and then checking should you add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be better to see your whole code to show you the right places, but the flag-solution by Kevin could look like this:

```
private boolean isAtEnd = false;

if (object.getIsLast()) {
    isAtEnd = true;
}

if (!isAtEnd) {
    addobject.add(object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestRing extends Activity
{

boolean isLastObj = false;
Button add;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testring);



    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {

            if(!isLastObj)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < addObject.size(); i++ )
                {
                    Object newboject = addObject.get(i);
                    newboject.setTitle("stuff");
                    newboject.isLast = false;
                    newboject.add(object);

                    if(newboject.getIsLast)
                    {
                       isLastObj = true; // this will prevent furtheradding of objects

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fixed-size list from your list that already contains all the items (and the last one) and pass it to the adapter as:

```
List<Object> finalObjectList = Arrays.asList(addObject);
```

Please be advised that adding an element to this list will throw an `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Answer (score 0):

Logic(Works with Ordered collections only): Check 'isLast' field of the last element in your list.

```
if(addObject.size() > 0 && !addObject.get(addObject.size()).getIsLast()){
    Object object = new object;
    object.setTitle("stuff");
    object.isLast = false;
    addObject.add(object);
}
```

Though the solution is bit clumsy, but it is a contained logic and won't depend on external flag.